# A question regarding derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is regarding the the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^2$. I am trying to follow the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8_3PFjiJvY). In the video at 2:14 it says that $dy$ is 4 times $dx.$ But suppose $x$ goes from 2 to 2.5. So $dx$ is .5. Then $y$ goes from 4 to 6.25, so $dy$ is 2.25 and not 4 times .5 i.e 2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $dy = 2xdx$ so when $x=2$, $dy=4dx$. The derivative is the instantaneous change so it doesn't make sense to talk about the derivative when $x$ goes from $2$ to $2.5$. In fact, at $x=2.5$, $dy=5dx$.

Comment: @JohnDouma You are absolutely correct. I too observed the same. His terminology is right, but the way he marks the graph and phrases it is a bit misleading. Can you tell a better way how to phrase the concept? Should he not say that $dy$ approaches 4$dx$?

Comment: I understand your confusion. How much calculus have you had? Are you familiar with using the derivative to compute the slope of the tangent line and the tangent line as a linear approximation to a curve at a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative defines a linear map that approximates the original function at a point. In this case we have that $\frac{dy}{dx}=4$ at $x=2$ so near the point $(2,4)$, we can approximate changes in $f$ by $dy=4dx$. (Notice the similarity between this and $y=4x$)

This is the equation of a line in a coordinate system whose origin is $(2,4)$. The expression that @Robbie has shows the difference between the actual function's value at $x=2$ and its approximation. That's the $o(dx)$ term.

The larger $dx$ is, the less accurate the approximation is.
In your particular example, $0.5$ is a relatively large change so you see the discrepancy between the linear approximation and the actual change. In fact, $(0.5)^2=0.25$ which is exactly the difference you found between the approximated  $dy=2$ and the actual $dy=2.25$.

Answer (score 0):

To first order in $dx$, it's four times. Essentially he just means
$$
dy = (2+dx)^2 - 2^2 = 4dx + o(dx)
$$
– the definition of a derivative.

Comment: Yes. This is what I also observed. I think the way he marks the graph and says that $dy=4dx$ is a bit ambiguous/ misleading. Can you tell what would be a better phrasing for above?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're familiar with small-o notation. But $o(dx)$ means something that, when divided by $dx$, tends to zero as $dx$ tends to zero. The *infinitesimal* change *is* then $4dx$, because that's what you get in the limit $dx\rightarrow0$.